# Ionic view title not updating on transition to 'nephew' state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Basically I am trying to transition from my root.home state to root.topic.section (a topic view with a nested section view). The view loads but my back button and view title do not appear. The view title stays the same as it was in root.home. I don't understand because when i use ui-sref to change to sibling state (with no child states) then it DOES change the title.

**EDIT:** When I navigate from root.home to a sibling page root.dbtest, dbtest created a new navbar element in the DOM with the correct title, and sets the home's navbar to 'cached'. But when I navigate from root.home to root.topic.section no new DOM element is created and home remains active.

**EDIT 2** this is the 'ui-sref' i am using to link to the sub state from root.home.

```
<a ui-sref="root.topic.section({topicId: xxx, inStore: false, topicName: xxx, sectionType: SECTION_TYPE.Summary})">link</a>
```

.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url: '/root',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu-static.html',
        controller: 'MenuCtrl'
    })
    .state('root.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.topic', {
        url: '/topic/:topicId/{inStore}',
        abstract: true,
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/topic-view.html',
                controller: 'TopicCtrl'
            }
        },
        params: {topicName: null}
    })

    .state('root.topic.section', {
        url: '/section/:sectionType',
        views: {
            'sectionSpace': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/topic-section-view.html',
                controller: 'TopicSectionCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

Here is a snippet from my menu-static.html

```
<ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view name="menuContent">

  </ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

Here is a snippet from home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="All Topics">
  <ion-nav-title>All Topics</ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is a snippet from topic-view.html

```
<ion-view view-title="NOT SHOWING">
  <ion-nav-title>NOT SHOWING</ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-nav-view name="sectionSpace">
    </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I think this happens when the ionic child state doesn't have a standard menu/tab implementation. So if you put tabs in All Topics it will work better also by the way you have an extra > on home.html

Comment: @Zargold not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Also: the Url will currently be /root/topic/... This seems undesirable=> you can have root have the `url: '',` and this will allow the url to be /topic/
The above did not work well for me so I tried this personally and it did work for the Parent:

Topic-view.html

```
<ion-view view-title="NOT SHOWING">
    <div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-balanced tabs-color-light">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a ng-repeat='section in ["Section1", "Section2", "Section3"]' class="tab-item" ng-click='goTo(section.toLowerCase())'>
        {{section}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ion-nav-view name='sectionSpace'></ion-nav-view>
</ion-view>
```

And it did work.
I'm not sure what this {inStore} is about but maybe that's for earlier versions of Ionic/Angular I think I got this working in this codepen: http://codepen.io/zargold/pen/qZNJNJ?editors=1011

Comment: I mean the tabs work and look nice, but my issue is that the view title still doesnt display the correct text once it has changed views (from home to topic.section). For some reason the nav bar element never gets created and the previous views nav title still appears

Comment: hmm I believe this fixed it for me in a similar situation but let me try to make a jsFiddle what version do you have?

Comment: My parent state is also not abstract didn't really see the point of it being abstract.

Comment: Ionic 1.1.1, I just don't see why it wouldn't update @Zargold

Comment: I just tried something. Changed my ui-sref to go to root.topic and not root.topic.section and it works, updates the title correctly and adds the back button, so why can't I go to a section?

Comment: The back button works on root.topic before I have navigated to any of the root.topic.section states, and then it remains there but doesn't do anything

Comment: See the codepen and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Hey I really appreciate you taking the time to work that codepen up and help me with this problem. Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't even possible.. I am trying to link to a specific section, not just the root.topic state with the sections available in it. In your menu ui-sref you have routed to root.topic and not to a specific section

Comment: Hi alsco77: If you'd like I did make a change to have it be like that then the rest of the child states are available. What do you specifically need out of the parent scope? either way you can check it out like that.